# How can I center my menu in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a CSS horizontal menu in the middle of the `header` element and make sure that it stays in the middle when resizing the browser window. I of course tried `margin: auto;`, but it also did not work for me.

### [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/czqKV/4/embedded/result/)

```
header .center {
  background: url(../images/header-center.png) no-repeat;
  width: 510px;
  height: 100%;
  /*margin: auto;*/
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beyond the `margin: 0 auto;` you need to also change the `#navigation` by removing the `position: absolute;` and the `left: 260px;`

Please also notice that you are giving a bigger size to the menu `#navigation` and a smaller size to the header that contains it with the `.center` class.

### Complete fix to your issue:

```
header .center {
  background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/sh/1mp20mw7izrycq2/fUbLOQUbN0/pingdom-theme/images/header-center.png") no-repeat;
  width: 510px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation {
  width: 705px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

The reason your code was not working is because you were just doing `margin: auto` which should technically work because it's giving your: top, right, bottom and left sides a margin of `auto` and while this is all fine, your `#navigation` still has the position properties which are not letting you center it.

### So just as a final lesson:

Everytime you declar something like `margin` , `padding` , `border` etc... you can do two types of shorthand notation to them to take care of all the sides.

`margin: 0 auto` means: Margin top and bottom 0 and margin left and right auto.

Comment: Damn he failed to mention theres a position:absolute; makes my answer kinda useless now.

Comment: I had to try it myself to see why it was not working with `margin: auto` as it technically should still work without the 0... and I notice that there was a position absolute there hehe... Cheers anyways to making the site the best QA database that we can.

Comment: I'll delete my question yours is going to be helpful for his situation.

Answer (score -1):

here you go

```
header .center {background: url("https://dl.dropbox.com/sh/1mp20mw7izrycq2/fUbLOQUbN0/pingdom-theme/images/header-center.png") no-repeat; width: 510px; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}

#navigation {width: 705px;height: 50px; left: 50%; overflow: visible; margin-left: -255px;}
```

this should always be half of the parent container width 510px